# getting a sql answer in the same order that it was entered

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to get a song list from a DB.

I'm sending in the query line an array of ID'S (permalinks) and I want the return values will be in the same order I gave in the array. Is there a way to do that?

```
function getByPermalinks (permalinks, callback) {
var template = 'select video_digests.*, permalinks.redirect' +
    'FROM video_digests ' +
    'RIGHT JOIN permalinks on permalinks.internal_id = video_digests.media_key WHERE permalinks.permalink in (?)';

db.query(
    template,
    [permalinks],
    onGotVideos.bind(exports, callback)
);
```

}

Comment: Use an order by with a case statement. it's unusual to see a right join - not wrong necessarily, just unusual, and you may get nulls returned from video_digest if there are items in permalinks which are not in video_digest.

Comment: The results of a `select` without an `order by` clause are un-ordered: they might change even if nothing has (apparently) changed even if the request is repeated immediately. To get a specific order apply an `order by` clause.

Comment: @P.Salmon and Richard thank's for the reply I'm well aware that an 'order by' clause is necessary but the order that I need is the array order. The response from the DB doesn't have any values that I can sort by as I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by differences. The value of the difference is 0 in case of similarity and 1 otherwise. So, ordering by `c1 <> v1` means that the first matches will be the records whose `c1` column has `v1` value. In case of similarities, the second criteria is used for `c2 <> v2` and so on

```
order by c1 <> v1, c2 <> v2, c3 <> v3
```

Comment: Hi @Lajos Arpad Not sure how can I implement your solution since I am using an array and the columns retuning do not contain permalinks

Comment: @utabmedia you do not need to return the permalinks as a result in order to be able to order by them. You are able to find the pairs matching your criteria, you will just need to use this as an order as well.

Comment: thank's for your help, unfortunately my sql understanding isn't well enough to understand and implement your solution..

Comment: @utabmedia you will need an order by permalinks.permalink <> yourvalue1, permalinks.permalink <> yourvalue2 at the end of your query. Test by hard-coding the values at first at the order by and if it works well, make it parameterized.

Comment: is it possible to do with arrays ?

Comment: @utabmedia please, elaborate the exact idea you have. I would gladly answer the question according to the best of my knowledge then.